# How to show divisions in custom range slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on custom range slider for my website, where I had wrapped my [input type="range"] around a label and set opacity of input[type="range"] to zero. Everything is working fine but I am stuck in showing division.
Attached is the source code, Where I had Shared what I had achieved so far and What is left, For the convivence I had set opacity of range input to 0.1 so you can get the idea of what's going backend.
Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

```js
var rangeSlider = document.querySelector('#price_slider');
rangeSlider.addEventListener("input", rangeScript);

function rangeScript(value) {
  var target = document.getElementById('progress');

  let newValue = parseInt(this.value);

  switch (newValue) {
    case 4:
      target.style.background = 'linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 0%,#f5f5f5 0% )';
      break;
    case 5:
      target.style.background = 'linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 20%,#f5f5f5 0% )';
      break;
    case 6:
      target.style.background = 'linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 40%,#f5f5f5 0% )';
      break;
    case 7:
      target.style.background = 'linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 60%,#f5f5f5 0% )';
      break;
    case 8:
      target.style.background = 'linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 80%,#f5f5f5 0% )';
      break;
    case 9:
      target.style.background = 'linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 100%,#f5f5f5 0% )';
      break;
    default:
      target.style.background = 'linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 0%,#f5f5f5 0% )';
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>what I have achieved</h1>
<div id="progress" style=" width: 100%; background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 5%, #f5f5f5 0% ); ">
  <input id="price_slider" type="range" min="4" max="9" value="" style="opacity: 0.1; width: 100%; height: 50px" />
</div>
<h2> what I want to achieve </h2>
<a href="https://imgbb.com/">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/T81PXkn/slider.png" alt="slider" border="0"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also play with 2 gradients and eventually background-blend-mode:

here is the idea: https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/poeXepV

```js
var rangeSlider = document.querySelector("#price_slider");
rangeSlider.addEventListener("input", rangeScript);

function rangeScript(value) {
  var target = document.getElementById("progress");

  let newValue = parseInt(this.value);

  switch (newValue) {
    case 4:
      target.style.background =
        "  linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 0%,#f5f5f5 0% ),repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg,  transparent 0 calc(20% - 4px), gray calc(20% - 4px)  calc(20% - 2px), white  calc(20% - 2px) 20% )";
      break;
    case 5:
      target.style.background =
        "linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 20%,#f5f5f5 0% ),repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg,  transparent 0 calc(20% - 4px), gray calc(20% - 4px)  calc(20% - 2px), white  calc(20% - 2px) 20% )";
      break;
    case 6:
      target.style.background =
        "linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 40%,#f5f5f5 0% ),repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg,  transparent 0 calc(20% - 4px), gray calc(20% - 4px)  calc(20% - 2px), white  calc(20% - 2px) 20% )";
      break;
    case 7:
      target.style.background =
        "linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 60%,#f5f5f5 0% ),repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg,  transparent 0 calc(20% - 4px), gray calc(20% - 4px)  calc(20% - 2px), white  calc(20% - 2px) 20% )";
      break;
    case 8:
      target.style.background =
        " linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 80%,#f5f5f5 0% ),repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg,  transparent 0 calc(20% - 4px), gray calc(20% - 4px)  calc(20% - 2px), white  calc(20% - 2px) 20% )";
      break;
    case 9:
      target.style.background =
        "linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 100%,#f5f5f5 0% ),repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg,  transparent 0 calc(20% - 4px), gray calc(20% - 4px)  calc(20% - 2px), white  calc(20% - 2px) 20% )";
      break;
    default:
      target.style.background =
        "  linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 0%,#f5f5f5 0% ), repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg, transparent 0 calc(20% - 4px), gray  calc(20% - 4px)  calc(20% - 2px), white  calc(20% - 2px) 20% )";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#progress {
  background-blend-mode: color, normal;
overflow:hidden;
}

#progress:before {
  content: "4 5 6 7 8 9";
  display: block;
  margin-right: -10vw;
  background: white;
  letter-spacing: calc(10vw - 0.9ch);
}
```

```html
<div id="progress" style=" width: 100%; background:linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 60%,#f5f5f5 0% ), repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg, transparent 0 calc(20% - 4px), gray  calc(20% - 4px)  calc(20% - 2px), white  calc(20% - 2px) 20% )  ">
  <input id="price_slider" type="range" min="4" max="9" value="" style="opacity: 0.15; width: 100%; height: 50px" />
</div>
```

text alignment trick :

```js
var rangeSlider = document.querySelector("#price_slider");
rangeSlider.addEventListener("input", rangeScript);

function rangeScript(value) {
  var target = document.getElementById("progress");

  let newValue = parseInt(this.value);

  switch (newValue) {
    case 4:
      target.style.background =
        "  linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 0%,#f5f5f5 0% ),repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg,  transparent 0 calc(20% - 4px), gray calc(20% - 4px)  calc(20% - 2px), white  calc(20% - 2px) 20% )";
      break;
    case 5:
      target.style.background =
        "linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 20%,#f5f5f5 0% ),repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg,  transparent 0 calc(20% - 4px), gray calc(20% - 4px)  calc(20% - 2px), white  calc(20% - 2px) 20% )";
      break;
    case 6:
      target.style.background =
        "linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 40%,#f5f5f5 0% ),repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg,  transparent 0 calc(20% - 4px), gray calc(20% - 4px)  calc(20% - 2px), white  calc(20% - 2px) 20% )";
      break;
    case 7:
      target.style.background =
        "linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 60%,#f5f5f5 0% ),repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg,  transparent 0 calc(20% - 4px), gray calc(20% - 4px)  calc(20% - 2px), white  calc(20% - 2px) 20% )";
      break;
    case 8:
      target.style.background =
        " linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 80%,#f5f5f5 0% ),repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg,  transparent 0 calc(20% - 4px), gray calc(20% - 4px)  calc(20% - 2px), white  calc(20% - 2px) 20% )";
      break;
    case 9:
      target.style.background =
        "linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 100%,#f5f5f5 0% ),repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg,  transparent 0 calc(20% - 4px), gray calc(20% - 4px)  calc(20% - 2px), white  calc(20% - 2px) 20% )";
      break;
    default:
      target.style.background =
        "  linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 0%,#f5f5f5 0% ), repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg, transparent 0 calc(20% - 4px), gray  calc(20% - 4px)  calc(20% - 2px), white  calc(20% - 2px) 20% )";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.overflow-h {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#progress {
  background-blend-mode: color, normal;
  margin: 1em auto;
  transform: scale(0.99)
}

#progress:before {
  content: "4 5 6 7 8 9";
  display: block;
  margin-right: -10vw;
  background: white;
  letter-spacing: calc(10vw - 0.8ch);
  text-indent: -0.5ch;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-h">
  <div id="progress" style=" width: 100%; background:linear-gradient(  90deg, rgba(166, 152, 62, 1) 0%,#f5f5f5 0% ), repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg, transparent 0 calc(20% - 4px), gray  calc(20% - 4px)  calc(20% - 2px), white  calc(20% - 2px) 20% )  ">
    <input id="price_slider" type="range" min="4" max="9" value="4" style="opacity: 0.15; width: 100%; height: 50px" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: clicking on the first half selects the lower value, clicking on the second half selects the higher value clicking right on the middle is luck ;) . for the text on top of the lines , see if that is what you look for : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/poeXepV (tricked via text-indent and scale() to keep it on sight)

Comment: Alright! Thank you! I highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom range "component", a simple example is below, but you have to work on it a bit ;)

```js
const rangeSlider = document.querySelector('#price_slider');
rangeSlider.addEventListener("input", rangeScript);
const customProgress = document.querySelector('#customProgress');

for(let i = 0; i < rangeSlider.max - rangeSlider.min ; i++){
  const step = document.createElement('div');
  step.classList.add('step');
  step.setAttribute('data-label', +rangeSlider.min + i + 1);
  customProgress.appendChild(step);
}

customProgress.querySelector(`.step[data-label="${rangeSlider.value}"]`)
.classList.add('current')

function rangeScript(value){ 
  const target = document.getElementById('progress'); 
  
  let newValue = parseInt(this.value);
  const currentStep = customProgress.querySelector(`.step.current`);
  if (currentStep) {
    currentStep.classList.remove('current');
  }
  

nextStep = customProgress.querySelector(`.step[data-label="${newValue}"]`);

if (nextStep) {
  nextStep.classList.add('current')

}

}
```

```css
#customProgress {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
height: 25px;
background: red;
}

.step {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.step::after {
  content: attr(data-label);
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em;
  right: -.25em;
}

.step ~ .current,
.step.current {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>what I have achieved</h1>
<div id="customProgress">
  
</div> 
<div id="progress" style=" width: 100%;" > 
<input id="price_slider" type="range" min="4" max="9" value="" style="opacity: 0.1; width: 100%; height: 50px" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: you did very well with that, and came up with vey good solution. Is It possible that on clicking specific box slider gets updated so that we do not have to drag slider's thumb to update the custom bar?

Comment: Thanks, yes it is possible but you have to figure out it by yourself. HINT: add the event listener on `customProgress`  element and bind value from `data-label` to `rangeSlider.value`